# Universal iOS app with HealthKit not showing up in iPad App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, healthkit

We have an iOS application that uses healthkit but we handle all cases of it gracefully for our iPad Application. After a successful submission we are not able to download it from the App Store directly on an iPad, but we can download it through iTunes. Is there something we need to do to make it appear on the iPad's App Store as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found that we needed to weak link HeathKit in the Link Binary With Libraries section by making the Framework "Optional".

Comment: Not working for iPad  mini 3 with making healthKit Optional

Comment: @Firozzz make sure in your plist you remove it as a required capability.

Comment: worked, But can I submit this changes on AppStore so that i can use same application for iPad too?

Comment: Yes, since it is weak linked, it will support all devices.

Answer (score 4):

Does you plist contain `healthkit` under the required device capabilities? If it does, I'm guessing it won't show up on the iPad on the store, since the device doesn't fulfill the requirements. Downloading through iTunes won't filter out apps based on the requirements.

The fix would be to remove `healthkit` from the required capabilities and resubmit. The app should show up in the store for iPad then.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3

Comment: Exactly device should support Health Kit

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html